# Split Python Table inside Power Query

Tags: python, split, powerquery

I have collected a huge csv file and one of the fied looks like a Python Table (or Dictionnary)
Here is an example

```
[{"cas_id": "1763-23-1", "unit": "ng/l", "isomer": null, "substance": "AAAA", "less_than": null, "value": 40.0}, {"cas_id": "335-67-1", "unit": "ng/l", "isomer": null, "substance": "BBBB", "less_than": null, "value": 90.0}]
```

We can clearly view the structure of the string 'cas-id, unit, isomer, substance, ....' but for the moment, it's just a string field in Power Query.

I would like to know if there is a trick to convert the field into a Record or something like that, in order to split easily each item in different columns in Power Query

Thanks

Comment: [Parse text as JSON or XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/parse-json-xml)

Comment: Yes ! That's it
But my PowerQuery in French doesn't express "Parse" correctly. So I didn't find it in the ribbon